# Edit Box with Submit Button

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, edit, editbox

How can i add a submit button to an Edit Box in MFC(VC++). Similar to "Search Edit Box" in Windows Explorer or File Open Dialog in MS Office Applications.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or newer, you can use [CMFCEditBrowseCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983421.aspx). It's an Edit control with a button. You can customize the button image as well as the behaviour when the user clicks the button.